# Why is is my instance variable nil when using Storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to get LazyTableImages working with Storyboards and ARC.  My project compiles and displays "Loading..." and the Placeholder.png image.  My logs show that the Parser is retrieving most of the data (artist, appName) but has trouble with the thumbnail images (Bad URL).  The biggest problem seems to be here (the NSLog of nodeCount is always zero).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"RootViewController - tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    // customize the appearance of table view cells
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    // add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data
    int nodeCount = [self.entries count];

    NSLog(@"RootViewController - nodeCount is %d",nodeCount);

    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle                             
                                          reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];   
            cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";
        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle                                    
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSLog(@"RootViewController - nodeCount2 is %d",nodeCount);

    // Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
    if (nodeCount > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"RootViewController - nodeCount3 is %d",nodeCount); //this one never gets displayed

        // Set up the cell...
        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.appName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = appRecord.artist;

        // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
        if (!appRecord.appIcon)
        {
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];                
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = appRecord.appIcon;
        }

        NSLog(@"RootViewController - nodeCount4 is %d",nodeCount);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please show where you update `self.entries`.

Comment: I found the problem...it was because the AppDelegate method(s) for setting up the RootViewController is different between using NIBs and Storyboards...hence it wasn't getting alloc.  Adding the following to applicationDidLaunch solved it: rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
        [window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: And right after that entries are assigned to RootViewController like so:     self.appRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
    rootViewController.entries = self.appRecords; ... so if rootViewController doesn't exist, entries cannot exist...

Comment: Cool, you should add that as an answer to your question so you can later accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the AppDelegate method(s) for setting up the RootViewController is different between using NIBs and Storyboards...hence it wasn't getting alloc. Adding the following to applicationDidLaunch solved it:

```
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init]; 
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController; 
[window addSubview:rootViewController.view]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And right after that entries are assigned to RootViewController like so:

```
self.appRecords = [NSMutableArray array]; 
rootViewController.entries = self.appRecords;
```

... so if rootViewController doesn't exist, entries cannot exist...